# Django error 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: django, attributeerror

I'm writing my first django app from 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/
and i'm experiencing 2 problems.

My Models.py are

from django.db import models

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.question self.question                                                                                                                                                   
class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
     def _unicode_(self):
        return self.question
```

My First Error is when I do

```
 python manage.py shell
 from mysite.myapp.models import Poll,Choice
 p = Poll(question="What Your Name",pub_date"1990-02-04")
 p.save()
 Poll.objects.all()
 [<Poll: Poll object>, <Poll: Poll object>]
```

Why Doesn't it show { Poll: What's up? } instead

```
 [<Poll: Poll object>, <Poll: Poll object>]
```

My second question is when i type

```
 p = Poll.objects.get(id=1)
 p.question.objects.all()
```

I get this errror

```
 AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

how do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you must define your `__unicode__` method of your model, not `_unicode_`.In addition, the code you given  `return self.question self.question` is syntax invalid.
2. `p` is a poll instance, `p.question` is CharField not ForeignKey, has no attribute objects. `p` has objects, call `p.objects.all()` works well.

Answer (score 1):

1> its `__unicode__` not `_unicode_`

```
Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question, self.pub_date

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

2> objects function is a property of a document instance not a field, p.questions is a document field,

Comment: there is no self.question in choice